# What is the best way to update a GTK interface in a multithreaded application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtk

As I understood, I'm doing it that way:

### My main function launch some threads before entering into the gtk main loop.

```
boost::thread p4(sensors_get_informations);
gtk_main ();
```

### Thoses threads do some stuff, and then update the corresponding element in the interface.

```
void sensors_get_informations()
{
    while(!quit)
    {
       [...] //Doing some stuff
       gdk_threads_add_idle((GSourceFunc)update_label_sensors, &str_end); //Here the interface will be updated
       wait(1000);
    }
}
```

### And the function wich will update the element (here it's a label)

```
static bool update_label_sensors(....)
{
    [...]
    gtk_label_set_label(GTK_LABEL(label_sensors), label_string);
    [...]
    return false;
}
```

I have currently 5 threads working together, and it seems to work fine, but is this the usual way to do this, or is there a way to improve it ?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439933/gtk3-multithreading) someone present an other method to update something on the interface, but with some research it appears that updating widget from other threads than the main GTK thread sometime cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual way to do it. Updating widgets from other threads than the main GTK thread is not allowed and will cause your program to crash unpredictably.